# BGP loadbalancing: full bgp table vs default route only

Tags: routing, bgp, load-balancing

I'm trying to achieve this: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13762-40.html#conf3. The only difference here is that I am being sent the full BGP routing table.

I have following questions:

1. If the upstream is sending full BGP table instead of a default
   route, will the setup and logic described on that page work?
2. Should I ask just for a default route?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes it will work in the same way.  BGP prefers external to internal routes.
2. Probably.   It you are only connected to a single provider, there's no advantage to full routes.  Full routes make sense when you can choose among several providers.

Answer (score 1):

1. A default route is just a single route. If you receive the full BGP
   routing table, you just have many routes instead of one. The same
   logic applies to each individual route as it would for a single,
   default route.
2. You could just ask for a default route if you really have no need
   for the full BGP routes. You could also set your routers up to
   ignore the incoming BGP routes and supply your own default route.
   You need to decide that based on whether or not one router really
   does have a better route to specific networks, and you want to take
   advantage of that.

Comment: You apparently type faster than me ;)

Comment: Actually, your answer popped before I was done.